Select rows in Oracle SQL until a condition is met for different objects
In Oracle SQL I have timeseries data from cars of different people (e.g. driven km or used gas in liters). Some of the indicators are reported on a weekday basis, other on a monthly or quarterly basis.
For subsequent calculations, I want to select in SQL all subsequent rows of indicators per person until the first reporting gap appears. If there is no reporting gap, I want to select all rows per indicator per person.
Person   | Indicator|Date      |Prev_Date |Frequency| row_num | Status
-------  | -------- | -------- |----------|---------| --------| ------
A        | km       |2024/04/03|2024/04/02|Daily    | 1       |   OK
A        | km       |2024/04/02|2024/04/01|Daily    | 2       |   OK
A        | km       |2024/04/01|2024/01/31|Daily    | 3       |   not OK
A        | km       |2024/01/31|2024/01/30|Daily    | 4       |   not OK
A        | gas in l |2024/04/01|2024/01/01|Quarterly| 1       |   OK
A        | gas in l |2024/01/01|2023/01/01|Quarterly| 2       |   not OK
A        | gas in l |2023/01/01|2022/10/01|Quarterly| 3       |   OK
B        | km       |2024/04/03|2024/04/02|Daily    | 1       |   OK
B        | km       |2024/04/02|2024/04/01|Daily    | 2       |   OK
B        | km       |2024/04/01|2024/03/31|Daily    | 3       |   OK
B        | km       |2024/03/31|None      |Daily    | 4       |   not OK
B        | gas in l |2024/04/01|2024/01/01|Quarterly| 1       |   OK
B        | gas in l |2024/01/01|2023/01/01|Quarterly| 2       |   not OK
B        | gas in l |2023/01/01|2022/10/01|Quarterly| 3       |   OK

I used LAG() in SQL to append the timestamp of the previous observation to each row. Based on that I added a case construction which says "OK" if the time lag between the current observation's date and the previous observation's date is ok based on the reporting frequency of the indicator.
For every person and indicator I now want to select rows until the first row has status "not OK". This shall be included but subsequent rows for this indicator reported for this person should not be reported.
Any clue for the clueless how to get there?
Desired output is:
Person   | Indicator|Date      |Prev_Date |Frequency| row_num | Status
-------  | -------- | -------- |----------|---------| --------| ------
A        | km       |2024/04/03|2024/04/02|Daily    | 1       |   OK
A        | km       |2024/04/02|2024/04/01|Daily    | 2       |   OK
A        | km       |2024/04/01|2024/01/31|Daily    | 3       |   not OK
A        | gas in l |2024/04/01|2024/01/01|Quarterly| 1       |   OK
A        | gas in l |2024/01/01|2023/01/01|Quarterly| 2       |   not OK
B        | km       |2024/04/03|2024/04/02|Daily    | 1       |   OK
B        | km       |2024/04/02|2024/04/01|Daily    | 2       |   OK
B        | km       |2024/04/01|2024/03/31|Daily    | 3       |   OK
B        | km       |2024/03/31|None      |Daily    | 4       |   not OK
B        | gas in l |2024/04/01|2024/01/01|Quarterly| 1       |   OK
B        | gas in l |2024/01/01|2023/01/01|Quarterly| 2       |   not OK


where is your query?

From Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE for row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT person,
       indicator,
       dt,
       prev_dt,
       frequency,
       row_num,
       status
FROM   table_name
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY person, indicator
         ORDER BY dt DESC
         MEASURES
           NEXT(dt)     AS prev_dt,
           CLASSIFIER() AS status,
           COUNT(*)     AS row_num
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN (^ "OK"* "not OK")
         DEFINE "OK" AS CASE 
                        WHEN Frequency = 'Daily'
                        THEN NEXT(dt) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
                        WHEN Frequency = 'Quarterly'
                        THEN ADD_MONTHS(NEXT(dt), 3)
                        END = dt
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Person, Indicator, DT, Frequency ) AS
SELECT 'A', 'km',       DATE '2024-04-03', 'Daily'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'km',       DATE '2024-04-02', 'Daily'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'km',       DATE '2024-04-01', 'Daily'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'km',       DATE '2024-01-31', 'Daily'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'gas in l', DATE '2024-04-01', 'Quarterly' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'gas in l', DATE '2024-01-01', 'Quarterly' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'gas in l', DATE '2023-01-01', 'Quarterly' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'km',       DATE '2024-04-03', 'Daily'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'km',       DATE '2024-04-02', 'Daily'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'km',       DATE '2024-04-01', 'Daily'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'km',       DATE '2024-03-31', 'Daily'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'gas in l', DATE '2024-04-01', 'Quarterly' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'gas in l', DATE '2024-01-01', 'Quarterly' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'gas in l', DATE '2023-01-01', 'Quarterly' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



PERSON
INDICATOR
DT
PREV_DT
FREQUENCY
ROW_NUM
STATUS




A
gas in l
2024-04-01 00:00:00
2024-01-01 00:00:00
Quarterly
1
OK


A
gas in l
2024-01-01 00:00:00
2023-01-01 00:00:00
Quarterly
2
not OK


A
km
2024-04-03 00:00:00
2024-04-02 00:00:00
Daily
1
OK


A
km
2024-04-02 00:00:00
2024-04-01 00:00:00
Daily
2
OK


A
km
2024-04-01 00:00:00
2024-01-31 00:00:00
Daily
3
not OK


B
gas in l
2024-04-01 00:00:00
2024-01-01 00:00:00
Quarterly
1
OK


B
gas in l
2024-01-01 00:00:00
2023-01-01 00:00:00
Quarterly
2
not OK


B
km
2024-04-03 00:00:00
2024-04-02 00:00:00
Daily
1
OK


B
km
2024-04-02 00:00:00
2024-04-01 00:00:00
Daily
2
OK


B
km
2024-04-01 00:00:00
2024-03-31 00:00:00
Daily
3
OK


B
km
2024-03-31 00:00:00
null
Daily
4
not OK



fiddle

You can use your existing query (the one that results as the first table in this question). Use your query as a CTE (named it grid below) or as a subquery.  Use Min() Over() analytic function with Case expression to create a new column with first ROW_NUM for STATUS = 'not OK' per group. Filter the result with Where clause: (comments in code)
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :    (resulting dataset of your query)
    tbl (PERSON, INDICATOR, DT, PREV_DATE, FREQUENCY, ROW_NUM, STATUS ) AS
      ( Select 'A',' km',  '2024/04/03',  '2024/04/02', 'Daily',  1, 'OK' From Dual Union All
        Select 'A',' km',  '2024/04/02',  '2024/04/01', 'Daily',  2, 'OK' From Dual Union All
        Select 'A',' km',  '2024/04/01',  '2024/01/31', 'Daily',  3, 'not OK' From Dual Union All
        Select 'A',' km',  '2024/01/31',  '2024/01/30', 'Daily',  4, 'not OK' From Dual Union All
        Select 'A', 'gas in l',  '2024/04/01',  '2024/01/01', 'Quarterly',  1, 'OK' From Dual Union All
        Select 'A', 'gas in l',  '2024/01/01',  '2023/01/01', 'Quarterly',  2, 'not OK' From Dual Union All
        Select 'A', 'gas in l',  '2023/01/01',  '2022/10/01', 'Quarterly',  3, 'OK' From Dual Union All
        Select 'B',' km',  '2024/04/03',  '2024/04/02', 'Daily',  1, 'OK' From Dual Union All
        Select 'B',' km',  '2024/04/02',  '2024/04/01', 'Daily',  2, 'OK' From Dual Union All
        Select 'B',' km',  '2024/04/01',  '2024/03/31', 'Daily',  3, 'OK' From Dual Union All
        Select 'B',' km',  '2024/03/31', Null, 'Daily',  4, 'not OK' From Dual Union All
        Select 'B', 'gas in l',  '2024/04/01',  '2024/01/01', 'Quarterly',  1, 'OK' From Dual Union All
        Select 'B', 'gas in l',  '2024/01/01',  '2023/01/01', 'Quarterly',  2, 'not OK' From Dual Union All
        Select 'B', 'gas in l',  '2023/01/01',  '2022/10/01', 'Quarterly',  3, 'OK' From Dual 
      ), 
   grid AS
      ( Select * From tbl )

--    S Q L :
SELECT    PERSON, INDICATOR, DT, PREV_DATE, FREQUENCY, ROW_NUM, STATUS
FROM    ( Select   g.*, 
            --  below is new column that gets the first ROW_NUM for STATUS not OK
                   Min(Case When STATUS = 'not OK' 
                            Then ROW_NUM 
                      End) Over(Partition By PERSON, INDICATOR, FREQUENCY) "RN"
         From     grid g   --  grid is your query defined as CTE (or put it instead of grid as a subquery)
         Order By PERSON, FREQUENCY, DT Desc
       )
WHERE  ROW_NUM <= RN  -- filter out all rows after the first 'not OK' STATUS

There is FREQUENCY in Partition By clause in case you have same INDICATOR with different frequences - you can remove it if not needed.
NOTE:
We don't know the code of your original query, but it is very likely that you can select the first ROW_NUM of a STATUS 'not OK' in the query itself and use it later with or without the filter in Where clause (or with a different filter maybe)
/*      R e s u l t :
PERSON  INDICATOR   DT          PREV_DATE   FREQUENCY   ROW_NUM STATUS
------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ------- -----------
A       km         2024/04/03   2024/04/02  Daily             1 OK
A       km         2024/04/02   2024/04/01  Daily             2 OK
A       km         2024/04/01   2024/01/31  Daily             3 not OK
A       gas in     2024/04/01   2024/01/01  Quarterly         1 OK
A       gas in     2024/01/01   2023/01/01  Quarterly         2 not OK
B       km         2024/04/03   2024/04/02  Daily             1 OK
B       km         2024/04/02   2024/04/01  Daily             2 OK
B       km         2024/04/01   2024/03/31  Daily             3 OK
B       km         2024/03/31   null        Daily             4 not OK
B       gas in     2024/04/01   2024/01/01  Quarterly         1 OK
B       gas in     2024/01/01   2023/01/01  Quarterly         2 not OK     */

